# Confirming if dependent t-test does not look into individual pair

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I would like to confirm about dependent T-test. As per my understanding, that t-test validates if the mean of 2 classes are significantly different. However, that does not take into account the individual pair, so:

```
score_first_test={1,2,3,4,5}
score_second_test={6,7,8,9,10}
```

and

```
score_first_test={1,2,3,4,5}
score_second_test={8,7,10,9,6}
```

will yield the same/similar result. Am I correct?

Comment: As a heads up, “validates of the mean of 2 classes is significantly different” is super sketchy phrasing. You get the gist of what a two-sample t-test does, but there are some details missing from this phrasing. I suggest JBStatistics on YouTube, who has a video on common hypothesis testing misconceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which t-test you do. If you do a two-sample t-test (or Welch’s t-test), the the pairing doesn’t matter. In fact, there might not be any pairing; the sample sizes don’t even have to be equal.

If you do a paired t-test, however, it first calculates pairwise differences and then performs a one-sample t-test on those differences. In this case, the pairing is crucial.

Comment: Hi Dave, I looked at the formula of student's (paired) t-test and it consists of mean, std, theoretical value, and n. How can it consider the individual pair? Thanks.

Comment: You calculate those values from the pairwise differences.

Comment: @DarrenChristopher, in the case of the paired-sample $t$-test, the $i$th subject has two values, say, before ($j=1$) and after ($j=2$) a treatment.  Then the analyst computes $y_{i,diff}=y_{i,2}-y_{i,1}$ for $i=1, 2, ...,, n$.  So if you have $n$ subjects, you'll have $n$ differences of the "after" value and the "before" value.  You then find the mean of these $n$ differences, $\bar{y}_{diff}$ and carry out a simple $t$-test on these differences.  By matching up each subject's before and after value and subtracting the difference, you've taken into account the pairing.

Comment: That being said, the *title* of your posts asked about the dependent $t$-test.  This implies you are using a paired comparisons test because two measurements taken on the same subject are dependent/correlated.